# Heroku Deployment. Node_Modules. Multer. S3. S3Storage Error: Bucket is required, case undefined

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, heroku, npm, webpack

Attempting to deploy to heroku but getting error regarding "multer-s3 bucket"?

Notes

1. Deploy to Heroku causes issue - works fine locally
2. Permissions in s3 bucket Block public access ( all off )
3. ACL - bucket owner / everyone / - Objects list and Bucket ACL Read

bucket cors

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "POST",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://journii21.herokuapp.com/"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Heroku Config vars

```
1. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID | key
2. AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY | key
3. S3_BUCKET | bucket name
```

terminal response

```
2021-05-25T20:32:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-25T20:32:46.828378+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-05-25T20:32:50.382358+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-25T20:32:50.382367+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2021-05-25T20:32:50.382367+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2021-05-25T20:32:50.382367+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-25T20:32:53.135901+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/multer-s3/index.js:94
2021-05-25T20:32:53.135909+00:00 app[web.1]: case 'undefined': throw new Error('bucket is required')
2021-05-25T20:32:53.135910+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-25T20:32:53.135911+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-25T20:32:53.135912+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: bucket is required
2021-05-25T20:32:53.135913+00:00 app[web.1]: at new S3Storage (/app/node_modules/multer-s3/index.js:94:29)
2021-05-25T20:32:53.135913+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/node_modules/multer-s3/index.js:214:10)
2021-05-25T20:32:53.135913+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/s3-upload.js:40:12)
2021-05-25T20:32:53.135914+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
2021-05-25T20:33:18.608882+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=journii21.herokuapp.com request_id=fcfe14e1-73a3-485d-8ac8-651d1b3e0b8a fwd="73.241.169.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-25T20:33:19.187711+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=journii21.herokuapp.com request_id=fb3c5b9b-f66b-4d55-83fe-0d2853220ff9 fwd="35.245.188.175" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-05-25T20:33:19.193208+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=journii21.herokuapp.com request_id=a9d3f0ec-a5f1-4ee5-8bb8-b542b74352d6 fwd="35.245.188.175" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-05-25T20:33:19.326622+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=journii21.herokuapp.com request_id=457988a5-2e7c-4bf5-bc51-06d16b8ac7d9 fwd="73.241.169.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

s3 upload route

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const router = express.Router();
// LOAD ENV VARS
dotenv.config({ path: '../config/config.env' });
aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const checkFileType = (file, cb) => {
  const filetypes = /jpg|jpeg|png|svg/;
  const ext = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase();
  const extname = filetypes.test(ext);
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
  if (extname && mimetype) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb('Images only!');
  }
};
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  return checkFileType(file, cb);
};
const upload = multer({
  fileFilter,
  storage: multerS3({
    s3,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_DEV_BUCKET,
    acl: 'public-read',
    metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
    },
    key: (req, file, cb) => {
      const ext = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase();
      cb(null, `photo_${file.fieldname}_${Date.now().toString()}${ext}`);
    },
  }),
});
router.route('/').post(upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(req.file.location);
});
module.exports = router;
```

client request s3 function

```
const uploadFileHandler = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      };
      const { data } = await axios.post('/api/v1/upload', formData, config);
      setImage(data);
      setUploading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setUploading(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: You're reading the bucket name from `AWS_DEV_BUCKET` but you're setting `S3_BUCKET` in Heroku. Perhaps you meant to read `process.env.S3_BUCKET` when initializing `multerS3`.

Comment: I also have a config file with the process.env and appropriate variables.
`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx
AWS_REGION=us-west-1
AWS_DEV_BUCKET=xxx
AWS_PRO_BUCKET=xxx`

Comment: Yes but that config file with secrets should not be in git! Set those variables as Heroku environment variables.

Comment: I have the secrets in a .gitignore but i haven't experienced with setting and reading variables from heroku. Is it not okay to have my variables in a .gitignore?

Comment: It's correct that .gitignore includes config.env or other .env files - that way they're excluded from being uploaded! Just set those same variables as Heroku config variables and they will be accessible via process.env exactly like the variables in .env. `env` in both cases refers to "environment variables" - this is the same as Heroku's config variables.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and my app is up and running!